# Fitting a front hub, 15mm through axle and 95mm width, to a 100mm fork

Tags: compatibility, through-axle

I've got a front hub, Crank Brothers Cobalt 1, with a 15mm through axle. I'm trying to fit it on my 100x15mm fork. Other 100mm wide wheels fit no problem. But for some reason the front hub on my Crank Brothers hub is too narrow, it comes in at 95mm wide. I don't think i'm missing any end caps, I might have wrong end caps though. With a few 15mm washers it fits fine. Am I missing something?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe the endcaps are wrong? Can you show a photo? Did you contact CB support?

Comment: I have never heard of a 95-mm front hub. I think you are missing something.

Comment: I've added some pictures and contacted CB support. Apologies for the ziptie, its what I use to keep the washers around when I remove the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are missing an endcap. The trope is for them to get overlooked and even possibly thrown away off of a new wheel when you pull off the black plastic protective axle plugs and the endcap gets pulled off with it.

Comment: I don't see how there could or would be any more to the endcaps already on the wheel (As in the pics). I was thinking they might be the wrong endcaps (I bought the wheels used) but they fit the hub perfectly, they're just not long enough.

Comment: @MikeG I see what you mean. That's a weird situation. Wrong endcaps is a theory. I would email Crank Bros at this point. Running it at 95 is bad, something is going on here.

Comment: @MikeG Crank Bros has an endcap chart you can use to see what endcaps each generation of wheel is supposed to have: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tw2ym4khl9zu9a/Wheel-Front-Endcap-Compatibility-Chart-JAN19A.pdf?dl=0